# Connecting to database with Java

Tags: java

In preparation for an exam I am asked to debug and answer the questions below, but this goes over my head. Help much appreciated.

1. Assuming the syntax is correct, why will this code produce an
   error when connecting to the database?
2. Suggest two ways how to improve security of database connection in this code.

   ```
   import java.sql.*;

   public class UpdateCar { 
      public static void updateCarNum (int carNo, int empNo)
        throws SQLException {

        Connection con=null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt=null;

        try {
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:default:connection");

             pstmt= con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES " +
                                    "SET CAR_NUMBER = ? " +                          
                                    "WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = " + empNo);


             pstmt.setInt(2, empNo);
             pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }
       finally {
            if (pstmt != null) pstmt.close();
        }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why should we do your homework?

Comment: Do you know why we are using `PreparedStatement`? Do you think it was used correctly here?

Comment: Homework questions are allowed, but please break them down into specific questions and show us, what you have already tried.

Comment: do you know what **JDBC** and **databases** are?

Comment: This is not in good form. You really need to ask an informed question rather than essentially saying you don't understand. I would remove the question before it gets more down votes.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
      pstmt= con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES " +
                             "SET CAR_NUMBER = ? " +                          
                             "WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = " + empNo);


      pstmt.setInt(2, empNo);
```

to

```
      pstmt= con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES " +
                             "SET CAR_NUMBER = ? " +                          
                             "WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = ?");

      pstmt.setInt(1, carNo);
      pstmt.setInt(2, empNo);
```

And you should also read a bit about what JDBC is, and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DiverManager. in java there is jdbc driver that may not work with your database . try another driver for your connection